Upvoted comments on Staging Ground lose the highlighting after loading the page again
Steps to reproduce:

Visit any Staging Ground post.
Find a comment under the post. Notice the neutral state of the upvote button: 
Upvote a comment under the post. Notice that at this point the upvote is highlighted. 
Reload the page.

Expected result: the upvote button stays the same colour as step 3.
Actual: On reload, the button briefly flashes orange, then settles into a darker grey  seemingly signifying "disabled". Hovering over confirms it is disabled. 
Here is a demo of upvoting, then reloading the page a few times:


Nice catch, we were missing a state on the front-end for a disabled-but-upvoted comment. I refactored the states so that it would cover this case and it should be working properly now.
